# FireStore: How to merge timestamp data to existing document?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2

I am new to FireStore and and building an app where users can bookmark photo documents and show them on their personal feed. This works fine. Now, I want to be able to sort the bookmarks by bookmarked date when the user is viewing their personal feed (orderBy method). Thus, to make this happen, I figured I'd add a timestamp value at the moment the user bookmarks the document.

Here's my attempt. **I wanted to verify with the community whether this is a good way to do it. I am concerned about redundancy and extra writes.**

```
async addDocToFeed({state}, doc) {
 try {
          const feedRef = this.$fireStore
            .collection(`users/${state.userProfile.uid}/feed`)
            .doc(doc.id) 

          await feedRef.set(doc) < --- copy record to user's feed collection (see json sample below)
          const bookmark = this.$fireStore
            .collection(`users/${state.userProfile.uid}/feed`)
            .doc(doc.id)
          bookmark.update({
            bookmarked: this.$fireStoreObj.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
          })
          // })
          console.log('doc bookmarked')
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('error updating doc', error)
        }
}
```

Example JSON of `doc` before adding the timestamp:

```
{"id":"1KecNCqYlcVRjq4BLCbZ","comments":"__vue_devtool_nan__","url":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/vue-photoapp-api.appspot.com/o/photos%2F0.jpg?alt=media&token=ee23b95b-b5d8-4abe-b1b9-e335d591b413","tags":["router","Texas"],"filename":"0.jpg","description":"test with new router setup","createdAt":{"seconds":1596020630,"nanoseconds":473000000},"title":"test with new router setup","status":"Unsolved","userId":"SvuTxDtHXJdBHImNQWByqnO3F2U2","displayName":"MrRouter"}
```

I tried to do:

```
await feedRef.set({doc, bookmarked: this.$fireStoreObj.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()}, {merge: true})
```

but that erased all the data and only added the bookmarked timestamp.

Thanks for any advice or assurances I'm on the right track (or not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  this    
      .$fireStore
      .collection(users/${state.userProfile.uid}/feed)
      .doc(doc.id);
      .set({
          bookmarked: Date.now()
      }, {merge: true})
      .then(() => {
          resolve(true);
      }).catch((error) => {
          reject(error)
      })
```

This should work.

Comment: I get an error `resolve is not defined`. Never seen resolve() before. Thanks.

Comment: @redshift Oeps sorry, I didn't wrap the code in a promise. 
add `return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {   this    
      .$fireStore
      .collection(users/${state.userProfile.uid}/feed)
      .doc(doc.id);
      .set({
          bookmarked: Date.now()
      }, {merge: true})
      .then(() => {
          resolve(true);
      }).catch((error) => {
          reject(error)
      })`